# Special prefix in CSS properties

Tags: css

In our compony we use ant design library. And when I added one of the components from the library to my project and I looked in Chrome DevTools I was amused that I found a property that called **--antd-arrow-background-color: none;**

Before I thought that all browsers can understand and show only properties from W3C standard that is from this list https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/index.php
But how is possible that my browser (Chrome) understans other properties? For example properties that have **antd** prefix?

Can anybody explain me this?

**PS** I know that there are vendor prefixes but there is no such prefix as antd among of them.

Comment: [CSS variables/custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are [Custom Properties: CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*)

> Property names that are prefixed with --, like --example-name, represent custom properties that contain a value that can be used in other declarations using the [var()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var) function.

Example Usage:

```css
:root {
  --color-primary: #6610f2;
  --color-secondary: #f8f9fa;
}

.primary-text {
  color: var(--color-secondary);
  background-color: var(--color-primary);
}
```

```html
<div class="primary-text">Hello World</div>
```

[:root](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:root) in HTML represents `<html>` element

> The :root CSS pseudo-class matches the root element of a tree representing the document. In HTML, :root represents the  element and is identical to the selector html, except that its specificity is higher.

Answer (score 1):

They are custom properties that work like variables and can be used like this:

```
:root{
    /* Property starts with "--" */
    --color-blue: #0000FF; 
}

body{
    /* Can be used with: var() */
    color: var(--color-blue); 
}
```

More info can be found here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties